# Assigning flights to baggage handling workstation in Python/PuLP

Tags: python, pulp

I am working on fairly big problem and I got stuck. I'll try and simplify it here hoping that someone can give me an idea...

Let's assume we have 25 flights (FlightID) departing at different times (TimeIndex) that have to be allocated to 10 available baggage handling workstations (WS), as shown below:

[image: Flights information]

Each flight requires 1, 2 or 3 baggage handling workstations (WS) that will be occupied from StartTime till EndTime. Each workstations can only serve one flight for the whole time period (StartTime to EndTime).

What I have so far looks like this:

First I am reading my information from the .csv file.

```
from pulp import *
import pandas

#Function to read from csv filename to dictionary dictname
def read_file(filename, dictname):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # Get the CSV reader and skip header
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader, None)
        for row in reader:
           #First column is the key, the rest is value
           dictname[row[0]] = row[1:]
           # Print result
           # print(row[0], ':', dictname[row[0]])

# Read flight departures from csv file
flights = {}
flights_csv = '25_busySO.csv'
read_file(flights_csv, flights)
```

I then create my 10 workstations.

```
chutes = []
for i in range(1,11):
    chutes.append('ws' + str(i))
```

Next, I am declaring my decision variable "x" - a dictionary with the combination of flight, time, workstation as key and 0, 1 as value.

```
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', [(f, t, c) for f in flights.keys() for t in \
    range(int(flights[f][1]),int(flights[f][2])+1) for c in chutes], 0, 1, LpBinary)
```

Declaring the problem with dummy objective function.

```
simploc = LpProblem('simploc', LpMinimize)

simploc += 0
```

First constraint forces all the flights to be allocated to a workstation to all the 24 required times.

```
for f in flights.keys():
    simploc += lpSum(x[f, t, c] for t in range(int(flights[f][1]),int(flights[f][2])+1) \
    for c in chutes) == 24
```

This creates a unique set of times in order to create constraints only when they are needed instead of going through a range of all possible times.

```
times = []
for k in x.keys():
    times.append(k[1])
times = sorted(set(times))
```

Next constraint forces one workstation to be only allocated to one flight at one 
time.

```
for t in times:
    for f in flights.keys():
        try:
            simploc += lpSum(x[f, t, c] for c in chutes) <= 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Just writing the model in a .txt.

```
simploc.writeLP('simploc.txt')
simploc.solve()
# print problem status and objective value
print("problem status", LpStatus[simploc.status])
```

I am also using pandas to get a visualization of "x".

```
# transfer results from x lpvariable dictionary to dataframe for easy reading
result = {}
for k, v in x.items():
    result[k] = value(v)
result = pandas.Series(result).unstack()
```

Now, my problem is that I do not know how to make the third constraint so that one workstation (WS) is allocated to the same flight for all the times needed by that flight, as seen below:

[image: Result so far.]

More precisely, Flight01 should, for example, be allocated to WS1 for all the times (from 116 to 140).

Comment: Perhaps you should specify a bit better what trouble you're running into. "How can this efficiently be implemented" is a bit too broad to ask, since there could be numerous implementations that will work. Do you have any code to show we can help you with?

Comment: Have you attempted any solutions yourself and encountered a specific error, or are you looking for a full solution? Typically this site is used for troubleshooting, rather than providing a full solution.

Comment: Hire someone to find out.

Comment: This sounds like you have a job you need done and you came to StackOverflow to see if someone would just give you copy-pasteable code that you didn't have to pay for? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What you are missing is that what I've posed here is a very scaled-down version of the project I am working on. If I just wanted it done I would have already paid someone to so it, like someone kindly suggested above. What I really wanted was some other views on this problem so I can get an idea how to unstuck myself. But, apparently, some have achieved such a high level of "coolness" that they forgot that they also had to learn how to use a fork...

Comment: @Bono I've added more details. Sorry, I realize now how broad my question is. I hope I clarified it a bit now..

Comment: @doydoy I've added more details. Sorry, I realize now how broad my question is. I hope I clarified it a bit now..

Comment: Great turnaround! :) I've upvoted your question since it shows a lot more research effort now, and something we can help with! I'm not exactly sure how to get the "on hold as off topic" flag gone. Hopefully someone will be able to help you on your quest(ion)!

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Much better. Changed my vote & voted to reopen.

Comment: Agreed, this is a much better question now.